# Deleting an item from a list which is a value in a given dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, key-value

```
myDict={0:[1,2,3,4],1:[0,2],2:[0,1],3:[0,4],4:[0,3]}
```

Hi, being new to the concept of dictionaries I am unable to figure out how to delete an item from the list of any key value pair. Lets say I am on myDict[0], my concern is how do I delete lets say the values 1 and 2 of 0:[1,2,3,4] list. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
myDict = {0: [1, 2, 3, 4], 1: [0, 2], 2: [0, 1], 3: [0, 4], 4: [0, 3]}

myDict[0] = [3, 4]  # Whatever here
'''
You can treat myDict[0] as a normal list
'''
myDict[0].remove(3)  # Same as list.remove(), because myDict[0] is just a list
print(myDict[0])
print(myDict[0][0])# Printing the 0th value in the list, which is myDict[0]
```

Comment: Got it! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

```
myDict = {0: [1, 2, 3, 4], 1: [0, 2], 2: [0, 1], 3: [0, 4], 4: [0, 3]}

myDict[0].remove(myDict[0][0])
myDict[0].remove(myDict[0][1])

print(myDict)
```